# How to pass windows Identity from angular app to asp.net core 2.0 webapi hosted on Linux server

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, pcfdev

I have an asp.net core web api running on Linux server (using PCF cloud). 
I want to pass user credential from angular app to this web api. I tried with angular option withCredentials = true but it is not passing user windows login id.

on Asp.net Core web api, I tried multiple options like

```
Context.User.Identity.Name
Environment.Username
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
```

but nothing seems to be working. I tried finding it out on google but no luck.
followed this url to setup but it is also not working...

```
https://www.koskila.net/how-to-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core/
```

If I run services locally on windows machine then everything works fine and I can get userid in my web api. I also tried hosting this asp.net core web api on Windows server IIS and it is also working fine.

The only issue comes when I host my service on PCF Linux box. I can understand Linux will not support the concept of Windows identity but is there any way I can pass just username with domain to asp.net core on Linux, I don't need full windows identity, just username will do.

Comment: In my option, it is impossible. As you know, windows authentication is not supported in linux container, you are not able to get the current user in linux server side. For angular, it is impossible to access the client user name as this is js access permission limitation.

Comment: Thanks Tao, I want to implement SSO in my app. Does it mean we can not enable SSO in angular app if server not on Windows?
Anything else we can pass from angular to Linux that can Identify user?

Comment: You may consider cookies authentication or asp.net core identity instead of windows authenticaiton. For windows authenticaion, it is impossible.

Comment: Thanks Tao... I'll explore other options as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no at the same time.
To support Windows authentication you need to be in the same domain and your OS can be able to pass creds to the web server (it should support this auth type).

There is nothing related to the UI. If you will try it locally you will find a lot of requests behind the scene that a really authenticate you.

I know that most of the popular web servers can do this with a lot of configuration, like keys import and you can't do this without changes in AD.

I think you need something like this https://www.axians-infoma.de/techblog/windows-authentication-in-docker-containers-just-got-a-lot-easier/